# Australian Visit Visa Subclass 600 Processing Time

Tags: visas, australia, pakistani-citizens

I know the general processing time from 15 to 27 days, but I have heard that they do process 90% of the Application within 7 days. I am just posting this question to see if anyone from our community had such experience where Sub Class 600 Application got approved/rejected within the first 7 days?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is a survey, not an objectively answerable question.

Comment: I disagree I am just trying to know that if someone has got the response before 15 days or not, cause I am trying to plan my schedule accordingly. I respect your opinion but please do not destroy the post.

Comment: You shouldn't leave your application until the last minute. If you're relying on "15-27 days" meaning "probably 7 days" then you're quite likely to have problems.

Answer (score 2):

The official statistics regarding visa processing times can be found on [the Department's Web site](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-processing-times/global-visa-processing-times).  This page is updated monthly.

As at 31 December 2018, the page shows that:

- 75% of subclass 600 tourist applications are processed in 15 days
- 90% of applications are processed in 27 days
- Depending on demand at a particular location, applications can be processed in as little as 48 hours, to as much as more than 20 days